# Google ngram wizardry: is there a NOT(word) operator or similar

Tags: discussion, online-resources

Let's say we'd like to assess the relative frequency of `the same way` versus `in the same way`.

This wouldn't yield a true frequency comparison:  `(the same way),(in the same way)` because `(the same way)` would return true when it encountered "...*in* the same way..."

Is there something like `(-in the same way)` -- meaning *'the same way' not immediately preceded by 'in'*?

Comment: *the same way,the same way-in the same way* ... Or you could express it as a proportion: *in the same way/the same way*

Comment: So this query `the same way-in the same way` would subtract the {in the same way} subset from the {the same way} set?

Comment: @TRomano - Yes, you can do some elementary "algebra" in Ngrams. [Have a look](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mustard+and+ketchup%2Cketchup+and+mustard%2Cmustard+and+ketchup+%2B+ketchup+and+mustard&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: In this case, actually, you have to bracket the terms as [*(the same way)-(in the same way)*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(the+same+way)-(in+the+same+way)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28the%20same%20way%29%20-%20%28in%20the%20same%20way%29%3B%2Cc0). There are limits on the number of tokens you can treat.